# How to add prototype functions in "TypeScript style" to external modules?

Tags: typescript, prototype

I want to modify the prototype of the nodejs `module` module.

`@types/node` has an interface defined for this (`NodeModule`) but don't has anything when I `import` the module, so I have to `require` it.

```
import * as Module from "module"; // Error
var Module = require("module"); // Ok
```

The problem is that Module don't has any definition. Is returned as `any`.

I have this

```
export interface CustomNodeModule extends NodeModule {
    __thingy:()=>void;
}

Module.prototype.__thingy = function() {
    // things!
}
```

I have to create my own `CustomNodeModule` interface, but, how can I modify the `Module` prototype and also those functions know that they are part of a `CustomNodeModule` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some global file (one with no imports/exports), add the following:

```
declare module "module" {
    export = Module;

    var Module: ModuleConstructor;

    interface ModuleConstructor {
        new (id: any, parent: any): NodeModule;
        readonly prototype: NodeModule;

        Module: typeof Module;
        globalPaths: string[];
        /** @deprecated */
        requireRepl(...args: string[]): any;
        runMain(): void;
        wrap(script: any): any;
        wrapper: string[];
    }
}
```

> Note: sending a pull request to DefinitelyTyped with this would probably be accepted.

Then, in the module where you actually tack a new property on, you can write:

```
import m = require("module");

// This is a *global augmentation*.
// It adds to declarations in the global scope.
declare global {
    interface NodeModule {
        __thingy: () => void;
    }
}

m.prototype.__thingy = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: So I need to create my own module. Thank you! +1 for the `This is a *global augmentation*.`. Was important here.

Comment: Just noticed that the problem still persists. `__thingy()` function still don't knows that `this` is a `NodeModule`.

Comment: You can add a `this` type annotation in the type of `__thingy` (i.e. `__thingy: (this: NodeModule) => void`) TypeScript should be able to infer the type of `this` in the function body itself afterwards. Read more [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions), and turn on `--noImplicitThis` to be safer.

Comment: You're welcome! For the record, you shouldn't even need to add the annotation on the function expression, but it's definitely a style preference thing.

Answer (score 2):

Since TypeScript interfaces are open ended you shouldn't have to need to create another interface, you can just extend the existing one with your method.

```js
export interface NodeModule {
    __thingy:()=>void;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's true. Now I remember that I've read about that some months ago when I started with TypeScript :-/ +1 for that

Comment: Now the important question, how can I overwrite Module prototype so they know that the this instance is a NodeModule?

Comment: Oh yeah, now I remember why I've done this. When I don't do extend the interface, `NodeModule` is not mixed (maybe because comes from a `@types`, I don't know), so I created a custom interface. Was not a big deal. Check http://i.imgur.com/VtQHOyb.png and http://i.imgur.com/ojd2APj.png

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález if you have a better solution for your particular case please post it and mark it as the correct answer, so people will know. :)

Comment: I still don't have a solution. I was just telling why I created an interface extending NodeModules instead of directly adding parameters to it. Going to ask in GitHub as the question here don't has much visits. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: Hm, tsc should take into account your changes, maybe you need to import the file you do the prototype change somewhere else for the effects to take place?